# How can I hide table borders in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

When editing content that includes a table in ckeditor, it shows a border around table cells even though there is no border in the markup. This seems to be a convenience feature, so I'd like to be able to toggle it, perhaps via a checkbox in the toolbar. Is this possible? Perhaps there is a plugin of some sort that I have not configured? Thanks for your help.

[Screen shot of table borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uevtm.png)

Answer (score 4):

This this best example to hide table border. Key player is : startupShowBorders: false,

```js
$(function () {

            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("textarea", {
                width: 750, height: 500, fullPage: true,
                extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser',
                allowedContent: true,
                qtBorder: '0',
                startupShowBorders: false,
                ////pasteFilter: 'semantic-content',
                //// Custom stylesheet for editor content.
                //// contentsCss: ['content/css/html-email.css'],

                //// Do not load the default Styles configuration.
                stylesSet: []       
            });                    

        });
```